# VS2010: Watching variables is not possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, watch

I use VS2010 as my vb.net compiler but sometimes I cannot watch a local variable while debugging.

Actually, when I add my local variable to watch window, it says that :

```
'sm' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

'sm' is my local variable and has beed declared within my routine.

Here is some my simple code snippet:

```
Public Sub Calculate()
    Dim sm As String        
    Dim c(2) As Byte
    c(0) = 49
    c(1) = 85
    c(2) = 121
    sm = Encrypt_Str(c)
    '...
    '...
End Sub
```

Well, I cannot watch 'sm' after the line `sm = Encrypt_Str(c)`. What causes this?

Comment: Pease supply some code sample

Comment: Is it possible you aren't stopped at a break point within the function, after the local variable is declared?  Unless the variable is currently in memory, you'll see the error you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was going into the project properties, selecting the 'Debug' tab and then ticking the 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process' box.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using something like

```
For Dim i as Intenger To something
  //Do something
Next i

something() //You are debuging here
```

The variable wount appear on Watch since it just exists for that block of code.
But is only a guess. I could be better if you post some code

Comment: Better not try to use that code in VB.NET. Comments are written using a single quotation mark: `'`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't watch any of my controls / variables..
Cleaned and rebuilded but that didn't help either, I created a new configuration in the configuration manager and copied my debug settings et voila my watch worked like a clock again ;)

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I recently had exactly the same issue in Visual Studio 2013. I was debugging VB.NET code in an ASP.NET code behind class. I could break point, step over and into statements, but trying to view / watch a variable would result in that error:

```
'myvar' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

What worked for me was:

1. Do a clean of the entire solution - so, right click on the solution in the solution explorer window then select Clean Solution.
2. Rebuild the solution.
3. Run in debug mode - variable can now be viewed / watched.

Happy coding.